# Handling music playback in a multiple activity application

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, media-player, playback

There are several activities in my application, and there is a music playing at the background, and what I want to achieve is that the music should start when the application starts and finish playing when application goes to background. Is there any simple workaround, or I should implement some kind of system that manages the playback in every activity? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this link will help you do it without using service : http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Play the music file using the service which can be start and stop at any time you want.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, since I can't know exactly where to stop the service. User can walk from one activity back to the previous - and then I should not stop the playback, but he also can close the whole app - and that's the time to stop it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check the ActivityManager to know information about your Application state and all.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing it using the MediaPlayer service is the neatest way you can achieve this.

If you implement it in the activity you will have to -

- Each activity will need to know the current song you are playing, the current time of the playback.
- When you launch a new activity you will have to stop the mediaplayer in the current activity and relaunch it the in new activity and seek it before you can start playing it back.
- There will be glitch in the audio playback. Which becomes annoying to the user if he keeps switching between the activities.

If you implement it as a service -

- You need to communicate to the new activity that the music is playing. Just pass a boolean (`isplaying`)
- Each activity will or rather should know if it is last activity before the app itself is closed. If it knows this info, then all it needs to do is check for the flag and re acquire the service and close it before it exits.
- There will be no glitches during the switch between activities.

Comment: In fact, there is just one soundtrack and it just loops forever. The main problem is that every activity can be last, since user can just press the hardware Home button and the music will remain playing, which is a big trouble.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem I was talking about, you cannot launch a mediaplayer instance in one activity and forget about it, you will have to take with you to each in every activity. But with a service you can re acquire the service at any point of time but still play the sound in the background without any glitches..

Answer (score 0):

create a Class file which extends Application tag, and start playing the music in oncreate() method.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
        //start music in a service
    }
}
```

from the parentActivity, start other activities by calling Activity:StartActivityForResult(), so when the child activity ends, the parentActivity shall know when the activity ends;it results to Activity::onActivityResult().

In this case you can start playing the media in the main parent activity and you may end the music(service) when pressing back.

Incercept any HomeButtonClicks in all the activies and pause/stop the player(end the service).

Comment: First of all handling Home Button clicks allowed only for Launher apps. Second is that starting playing music in Application object and stoping in other place is bad practice.